# Previous page, next page javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tryed to figure out how to go 1 page up and down with simple links but I couldn't find the answer which helped me out. I have got this url: https://pack-simulator.nl/jsondecode.php?page=1 whenever the button next page is clicked, it has to go to ?page=2 and when the previous page is clicked go to ?page=1 again. The script has a maximum of page 695 and minimum of page 1. I used this code,

```js
var pageNumber = location.search.split("=")[1];

$('a.next').click(function(){
    pageNumber++;
    if (pageNumber > 695) pageNumber = 695; // or set to 1
    window.location = ("?page=" + pageNumber);
}
$('a.prev').click(function(){
    pageNumber--;
    if (pageNumber < 1) pageNumber = 1; // or set to 695
    window.location = ("?page=" + pageNumber);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="prev" href="#">Load Prev page</a><br>
<a class="next" href="#">Load Next page</a>
```

I hope somebody can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: why can't you set the `href` at server? ... you know what page it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you try to accomplish with all those vars. If you try to load pages into content via ajax my code will not work, but if you want to simply use window.location to make the browser fetch another page you could try something like this:

```
var pageNumber = location.search.split("=")[1];

$('a.next').click(function(){
    pageNumber++;
    if (pageNumber > 695) pageNumber = 695; // or set to 1
    window.location.search = ("?page=" + pageNumber);
    return false;
});
$('a.prev').click(function(){
    pageNumber--;
    if (pageNumber < 1) pageNumber = 1; // or set to 695
    window.location.search = ("?page=" + pageNumber);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ah yeah I was too quick.... probably needs return false on the click to prevent that... edited and changed window.location to window.location.search

Comment: And properly closed the click handler

Comment: I see you got it working. Hope it was useful. BTW, splitting of the pageNumber like this only works well with a single param. If you ever add more you 'd need a more robust way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Check [image: this] out. the _page variable holds 'jasondecode.php' and _current variable holds 'jasondecode'. parseInt on _current thus fails.

location.search holds "?page=1".
So,
if you change

_url to `var _url = location.search.split('?')[1].split('=')`

and _page to `var _page = url[0]`

and _current to `var _current = parseInt(url[1])`

and form the request variable like

`var request = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/' + _href + "?" + _page + '=' + (_current + 1) + '.html';`

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to go to a certain page in your browser's history, try this:

```
<a class="prev" href="#" onclick="prev()">Load Prev page</a><br>
<a class="next" href="#" onclick="next()">Load Next page</a>
<script>
    function prev() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    function next() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
</script>
```

When a link is clicked, the browser will load either the previous or next page in its saved history.

If you are not planning to call these functions later, simply take out the  tag and its contents and replace the prev() and next() with the contents of those functions like this:

```
<a class="prev" href="#" onclick="window.history.back()">Load Prev page</a><br>
<a class="next" href="#" onclick="window.history.forward()">Load Next page</a>
```

Hope this helps!